# Fast solution to Subset sum algorithm by Pisinger

Tags: algorithm, subset-sum

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809436/fast-solution-to-subset-sum). I still find it very interesting problem and as there is one algorithm which deserves more attention I'm posting it here.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#cite_ref-Pisinger09_2-0): *For the case that each xi is positive and bounded by the same constant, Pisinger found a linear time algorithm.*

There is a different paper which seems to describe the same algorithm but it is a bit difficult to read for me so please - does anyone know how to translate the pseudo-code from page 4 (`balsub`) into working implementation?

Here are couple of pointers I collected so far:

http://www.diku.dk/~pisinger/95-6.ps (the paper)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9952759/1037407
http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/pisinger/codes.html

PS: I don't really insist on precisely this algorithm so if you know of any other similarly performant algorithm please feel free to suggest it bellow.

**Edit**

This is a Python version of the code posted bellow by oldboy:

```
class view(object):
    def __init__(self, sequence, start):
        self.sequence, self.start = sequence, start
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.sequence[index + self.start]
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.sequence[index + self.start] = value

def balsub(w, c):
    '''A balanced algorithm for Subset-sum problem by David Pisinger
    w = weights, c = capacity of the knapsack'''
    n = len(w)
    assert n > 0
    sum_w = 0
    r = 0
    for wj in w:
        assert wj > 0
        sum_w += wj
        assert wj <= c
        r = max(r, wj)
    assert sum_w > c
    b = 0
    w_bar = 0
    while w_bar + w[b] <= c:
        w_bar += w[b]
        b += 1
    s = [[0] * 2 * r for i in range(n - b + 1)]
    s_b_1 = view(s[0], r - 1)
    for mu in range(-r + 1, 1):
        s_b_1[mu] = -1
    for mu in range(1, r + 1):
        s_b_1[mu] = 0
    s_b_1[w_bar - c] = b
    for t in range(b, n):
        s_t_1 = view(s[t - b], r - 1)
        s_t = view(s[t - b + 1], r - 1)
        for mu in range(-r + 1, r + 1):
            s_t[mu] = s_t_1[mu]
        for mu in range(-r + 1, 1):
            mu_prime = mu + w[t]
            s_t[mu_prime] = max(s_t[mu_prime], s_t_1[mu])
        for mu in range(w[t], 0, -1):
            for j in range(s_t[mu] - 1, s_t_1[mu] - 1, -1):
                mu_prime = mu - w[j]
                s_t[mu_prime] = max(s_t[mu_prime], j)
    solved = False
    z = 0
    s_n_1 = view(s[n - b], r - 1)
    while z >= -r + 1:
        if s_n_1[z] >= 0:
            solved = True
            break
        z -= 1
    if solved:
        print c + z
        print n
        x = [False] * n
        for j in range(0, b):
            x[j] = True
        for t in range(n - 1, b - 1, -1):
            s_t = view(s[t - b + 1], r - 1)
            s_t_1 = view(s[t - b], r - 1)
            while True:
                j = s_t[z]
                assert j >= 0
                z_unprime = z + w[j]
                if z_unprime > r or j >= s_t[z_unprime]:
                    break
                z = z_unprime
                x[j] = False
            z_unprime = z - w[t]
            if z_unprime >= -r + 1 and s_t_1[z_unprime] >= s_t[z]:
                z = z_unprime
                x[t] = True
        for j in range(n):
            print x[j], w[j]
```

Comment: Here is my open-source javascript solution for the linear time, iterative 2004 algorithm by Pisinger which solves subset sum for each x_i positive and bounded by some constant C: https://github.com/thorpep138/subset-sum-pisinger and https://www.npmjs.com/package/subset-sum-pisinger . It has an open test suite and  follows precisely the algorithm outlined in https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-24777-7_4

Comment: I tried running this code as python3 and it failed because of missing parentheses on the prints. Just letting you know in case you want to add them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
// Input:
// c (capacity of the knapsack)
// n (number of items)
// w_1 (weight of item 1)
// ...
// w_n (weight of item n)
//
// Output:
// z (optimal solution)
// n
// x_1 (indicator for item 1)
// ...
// x_n (indicator for item n)

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int c = 0;
  cin >> c;
  int n = 0;
  cin >> n;
  assert(n > 0);
  vector<int> w(n);
  int sum_w = 0;
  int r = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    cin >> w[j];
    assert(w[j] > 0);
    sum_w += w[j];
    assert(w[j] <= c);
    r = max(r, w[j]);
  }
  assert(sum_w > c);
  int b;
  int w_bar = 0;
  for (b = 0; w_bar + w[b] <= c; ++b) {
    w_bar += w[b];
  }
  vector<vector<int> > s(n - b + 1, vector<int>(2 * r));
  vector<int>::iterator s_b_1 = s[0].begin() + (r - 1);
  for (int mu = -r + 1; mu <= 0; ++mu) {
    s_b_1[mu] = -1;
  }
  for (int mu = 1; mu <= r; ++mu) {
    s_b_1[mu] = 0;
  }
  s_b_1[w_bar - c] = b;
  for (int t = b; t < n; ++t) {
    vector<int>::const_iterator s_t_1 = s[t - b].begin() + (r - 1);
    vector<int>::iterator s_t = s[t - b + 1].begin() + (r - 1);
    for (int mu = -r + 1; mu <= r; ++mu) {
      s_t[mu] = s_t_1[mu];
    }
    for (int mu = -r + 1; mu <= 0; ++mu) {
      int mu_prime = mu + w[t];
      s_t[mu_prime] = max(s_t[mu_prime], s_t_1[mu]);
    }
    for (int mu = w[t]; mu >= 1; --mu) {
      for (int j = s_t[mu] - 1; j >= s_t_1[mu]; --j) {
        int mu_prime = mu - w[j];
        s_t[mu_prime] = max(s_t[mu_prime], j);
      }
    }
  }
  bool solved = false;
  int z;
  vector<int>::const_iterator s_n_1 = s[n - b].begin() + (r - 1);
  for (z = 0; z >= -r + 1; --z) {
    if (s_n_1[z] >= 0) {
      solved = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (solved) {
    cout << c + z << '\n' << n << '\n';
    vector<bool> x(n, false);
    for (int j = 0; j < b; ++j) x[j] = true;
    for (int t = n - 1; t >= b; --t) {
      vector<int>::const_iterator s_t = s[t - b + 1].begin() + (r - 1);
      vector<int>::const_iterator s_t_1 = s[t - b].begin() + (r - 1);
      while (true) {
        int j = s_t[z];
        assert(j >= 0);
        int z_unprime = z + w[j];
        if (z_unprime > r || j >= s_t[z_unprime]) break;
        z = z_unprime;
        x[j] = false;
      }
      int z_unprime = z - w[t];
      if (z_unprime >= -r + 1 && s_t_1[z_unprime] >= s_t[z]) {
        z = z_unprime;
        x[t] = true;
      }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
      cout << x[j] << '\n';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well....what can I say. This is as good as if it was written by the original author. I'm really, really thankful, it's a great piece of code. One last question: is it also possible to return all the items which contributed to the final sum?

Comment: Done, but not well tested. Proceed with caution.

Comment: +1. _Very_ nice. Since we were originally throwing this around in Python, I'm considering dropping an updated version that includes the solution instead of just `balsub`.

Comment: @MrGomez: please do! I'm doing the same already, I'm almost finished. Then, we can compare our versions and catch bugs from the translation.

Comment: Too bad it doesn't have any real comments and is just a piece of code.

Comment: Without comments, this code might as well be missing the newlines too.

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473707/modification-to-subsetsum-algorithm-by-pisinger

Answer (score -2):

great code man, but it sometimes crashed in this codeblock

```
    for (mu = w[t]; mu >= 1; --mu) 
    {
        for (int j = s_t[mu] - 1; j >= s_t_1[mu]; --j) 
        {
            if (j >= w.size())
            { // !!! PROBLEM !!!

            }


            int mu_prime = mu - w[j];

            s_t[mu_prime] = max(s_t[mu_prime], j);
        }
    }
```

...

Comment: Please add a reason for the failure if you can. Also, when does the code crash details would also be helpful.

Comment: I realy dont know, but I put this check
    if (j < w.size())
    {
     int mu_prime = mu - w[j];

     s_t[mu_prime] = max(s_t[mu_prime], j);
    }
and it works - same result set!

Comment: Put that info in your answer by [*editing*](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20498481/edit) it.