# Linear algorithm to find minimum subset sum over a threshold

Tags: c++, algorithm, subset-sum

I have a collection of N positive integers, each bounded by a (relatively small) constant C. I want to find a subset of these numbers with the smallest sum greater than (or equal to) a value K.

The numbers involved aren't terribly large (<100), but I need good performance even in the worst case. I thought maybe I could adapt Pisinger's dynamic programming algorithm to the task; it runs in O(NC) time, and I happen to meet the requirements of bounded, positive numbers.

[Edit]: The numbers are not sorted and there may be duplicates.

However, I don't understand the algorithm well enough to do this myself. In fact, I'm not even certain if the assumptions it is based on still hold...

-Is it possible to adapt this algorithm to my needs?

-Or is there another linear algorithm I could use that is similarly efficient?

-Could anyone provide pseudocode or a detailed explanation?

Thanks.

Link to the Subset-Sum code I was investigating:
[Fast solution to Subset sum algorithm by Pisinger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962568/fast-solution-to-subset-sum-algorithm-by-pisinger)

(Apologies if this is poorly worded/formatted/etc. I'm still new to StackOverflow...)

Comment: isn't this a variant of Knapsack Problem?

Comment: Yes. Specifically, a variant of Subset-Sum (itself a special case of Knapsack).

Comment: For future reference, try to avoid using the term "set" if there are duplicates. "collection" would be a better term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pisinger's algorithm gives you the largest sum less than or equal to the capacity of the knapsack. To solve your problem, use Pisinger to figure out what *not* to put in the subset. Formally, let the items be w_1, ..., w_n and the minimum be K. Give w_1, ..., w_n and w_1 + ... + w_n - K to Pisinger, then take every item that Pisinger does not.

Comment: I did consider doing the inverse operation, as you say, but then it is O(n(n-k)) = O(n^2), which is not linear.

Comment: @Athena The running time of Pisinger is O(item count * max item), which does not depend on the knapsack size or how many items the optimal solution stores.

Comment: Ah, you are correct! (I got my constants mixed up.) This will work for my purposes. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well one solution is to:

```
T = {0}

for x in V
   for t in T
       T.insert(x+t)

for i in K to max(T)
   if (T.contains(i))
       return i

fail
```

This gives you the size of the subset, but you can adapt to output the members.

The maximum size of T is O(N) (because of C bound), so the running time is O(N^2) and the space is O(N).  You can use a bit array of length NC as the backing store of T.

Comment: I don't think an O(N^2) algorithm counts as linear.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the title, I thought we were just trying for polynomial time.

Comment: I will clarify the question to say "linear". Thanks anyway.