# Given a collection of integers and threshold value T, divide the collection into as many groups as possible whose sum >= T

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, knapsack-problem, np

Given a collection of integers and threshold value T, divide the collection into as many groups as possible whose sum >= T.

The remaining integers (whose sum < T, so another group cannot be formed) should be left outside of the groups.

Constraints:

- length of the list <= 1,000
- values and T <= 1,000,000

Is there an algorithm for this problem in polynomial time?

For example given `[25,25,25,50,50,50,10]` and a threshold `T = 70` it should return:

```
[25,50]
[25,50]
[25,50]
Remaining: [10]
```

Selecting `[25,25,25]` as one of the groups would make it possible to only form one more group, `[50,50]` and the remaining values would be `[50,10]`. Two groups are not the optimal amount of groups, which is why this solution would be incorrect.

Comment: Why is not [25, 25, 25] a valid solution ?

Comment: Sorry, changed the remaining value to better illustrate. If we select [25,25,25], then we can only form one more group, for example [50,50]. By selecting [25,50], we can have 3 groups which is more.

Comment: Are all the integers positive? Are they bounded?

Comment: Positive and bounded as in description, <= 1,000,000

Answer (score 0):

There is no polynomial time algorithm for this since it contains as a special case the np-complete [Partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

Comment: Where can I read more about that? How do I know if its a special case?